# How to specify ordering in rethinkdb between query using index

Tags: rethinkdb

I want to do something like the following:

`r.db('mydb').table('tab').between(
  ['s', 0],
  ['s', 99999], {index: r.desc('s-t')})`

but this is not a correct Rql query:

```
RqlCompileError: DESC may only be used as an argument to ORDERBY. in:
```

Can I safely use

`r.db('mydb').table('tab').between(
  ['s', 0],
  ['s', 99999], {index: 's-t'}).orderBy({index: r.desc('s-t')})`

Will it be executed optimally (using single read instead of reading all records and then sorting them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you chain a `between` command with an `orderBy` one (using the same index), it will be executed in an efficient way.